# sudo npm uninstall node-sass: npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, node-sass

I am having trouble uninstalling node-sass from our react app.

My goal is to switch to sass from node-sass.

sass appears to be currently supported

When I uninstall node-sass I get the following error:

```
➜  nova-web git:(feature/tech-improvement-1204122945262264) ✗ sudo npm uninstall node-sass
Password:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: nova-web@21.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.10.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.11.13
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"^5.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!     1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR!   1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/material@5.11.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"^5.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.11.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!     @mui/icons-material@"^5.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2023-03-14T13_05_10_716Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2023-03-14T13_05_10_716Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried --force and --legacy-peer-deps flags with no solution.

Comment: If the dependencies are messed up you could just delete node_modules and package-lock.json. Then remove the package manually from package.json and run `npm install` to install everything fresh

Comment: unfortunately i don't have package-lock.json or node_modules since I am trying to use the latest version of yarn https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration. So I don't think this will resolve the issue